# Select text of all textView in absoluteLayout

Tags: android, textview

I have some TextView in AbsoluteLayout .I want to select all other textView when I select one textView.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    AppCompatTextView textView = new AppCompatTextView(context);
  String txt="txt"+i;

    textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    textView.setText(txt);

       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, x, y);


    textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    absoluteLayout.addView(textView);}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your code for this problem

Comment: @NandaZ this is my code.

Comment: I do not understand why do you have to using absolute layout, actually you can use Relativelayout or Framelayout instead since it was deprecated in level 27. I wrote my answer below, please check

Comment: Hi, I wrote simple projects that have similar problems. The goal is clear to give you inspiration to solve your problem. This is one alternative that you can do. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all other textView when I select one textView.

One alternative that you can do to select all Textview which is separate is by creating another button to Trigger select All, then your button calling this method. You can try this code

```
// ....
    AbsoluteLayout absoluteLayout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
    // ......
    // your dummy absoluteLayout
    private void selectAllText(View view){


        int num = absoluteLayout.getChildCount();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
            AppCompatTextView tv = (AppCompatTextView) absoluteLayout.getChildAt(i);
            tv.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            String thisTxt = tv.getText().toString();
            sb.append(thisTxt);
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        String allAppendText = sb.toString();
        // DO SOMETHING WITH FULL SELECTED TEXT

    }
```

---

**UPDATE**
This is interesting question so i created sample project to solve this. This sample might help your problem.
MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            CustomTextView tv = new CustomTextView(this);
            tv.setText("Text " + i);
            tv.setOnLongClickListener(view -> {

                if(!tv.isSelected()){
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    tv.setSelected(true);
                }else {
                    tv.setSelected(false);
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                return true;
            });

            linearLayout.addView(tv);
        }
    }

    public void showTextSelected(View view) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
            CustomTextView tv = (CustomTextView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            if(tv.isSelected()){
                String str = tv.getText().toString();
                sb.append(str).append("\n");
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "ALL TEXT : " + sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

CustomTextView.Java

```
public class CustomTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {
    private boolean selected;
    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        this.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        selected = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/mylayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:onClick="showTextSelected"
       android:text="SHOW" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can see the result as video here: [Result Video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/69n685bogz5pfmu/mobizen_20190212_212123.mp4?dl=0), **you can replace LinearLayout with AbsoluteLayout and add more params inside CustomTextView.**

Comment: how can i modify select text method?
or
how can i use this method?@NandaZ

Comment: maybe users just select one text of textview.
is it correct for this perpose?

Comment: Create new button, then that button will calling this method. i haven't test the code, but i think when you do `setSelectAllOnFocus` to all entire textview and then doing copy, probably all text will be save on clipboard(your problem solved). But it's just argument, you need to test it since i am being away from keyboard now

Comment: users maybe select one text of textview or more.your code select all text its not my purpose.I want users decide which text is select.

Comment: I give some data from server like text and x,y,width,height. I use dynamic text view to show each text on own position.but now I cant access to users select text .how can I do it? Is using canvas a good solution?@NamdaZ

Comment: One alternate you can do is to add new param in your textview, try make custom Textview widget which add new params "selected" then when this customtextview press long time you trigger the method inside (this method also executing setSelectAllOnFocus), if user selecting many textview just put it in arraylist which contains of your custom textview)